# optimum chess endgame with D=3 pieces doesn't give an exact moves_to_mate variable

Tags: engines, computer-chess, queen-endgame

I have just upgraded my code for computing completely optimally for both players a chess endgame as given here:
https://pastebin.com/jQ090L01 but it gives to me 2 plies to checkmate White instead of correct 4 plies according to StockFish.

Can someone give me a hint how to fix this and where is the source of the problem? The code is correct in the sense that it detects correctly the game_tree[1]['result']: -1 for black win, 1 for white's and 0 for a draw. But it gives wrong plies to mate.ChatGPT4 hasn't helped.

Comment: If you haven't already, it might also do to try Stack Overflow.